# What is the best way to wire up ReactiveCommand to invoke a webservice

Tags: reactiveui

I am some need help understanding the latest recommended approach to wire up and use reactiveui for a WPF project.

In doing research on the internet on reactiveui I came across various (few) posts spanning a long time period during which the library evolved with the unfortunate result that some of these how-to articles now refer to older ways of doing things which are no longer applicable

I am trying to understand the recommended way to wire up commands (usually to invoke web service which returns a DTO) and I’ve found multiple ways mentioned to do it.

My current understanding is that

```
// this is the first thing to do
MyCommand =  ReactiveCommand.Create()

// variations to wire up the delegates / tasks to be invoked
MyCommand.CreateAsyncTask()  
MyCommand.CreateAsyncFunc()  
MyCommand.CreateAsyncAction()  

// this seems to be only way to wire handler for receiving result
MyCommand.Subscribe  

// not sure if these below are obsolete?
MyCommand.ExecuteAsync  
MyCommand.RegisterAsyncTask()
```

Could someone try to explain which of these variations is the latest API and which are obsolete, with perhaps a few words about when to use each of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The changes on the ReactiveCommand API are documented in this blog post:
http://log.paulbetts.org/whats-new-in-reactiveui-6-reactivecommandt/

The first option - ReactiveCommand.Create() - just creates a reactive command. 
To define a command which asynchronously returns data from a service you would use :

```
MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(
                 canExec,  // optional 
                 async _ => await api.LoadSomeData(...));
```

You may use the Subscribe method to handle data when it is received:

```
this.Data = new ReactiveList<SomeDTO>();
MyCommand.Subscribe(items => 
{
    this.Data.Clear();
    foreach (var item in items)
        this.Data.Add(item);
}
```

Though, the simplest thing is to use instead the ToProperty method like this:

```
this._data = MyCommand
                .Select(items => new ReactiveList<SomeDTO>(items))
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.Data);
```

where you have defined an output property for Data:

```
private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ReactiveList<SomeDTO>> _data;
public ReactiveList<SomeDTO> Data
{
    get { return _data.Value; }
}
```